# Multiple AdMob rewarded videos using cocos2dx (c++) on android API

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x, rewardedvideoad

I am trying to load multiple rewarded videos from AdMob in my app. It's on cocos2d-x (C++) and we extended atomic-plugin-ads's code to handle AdMob's Rewarded Videos. This means that we make JNI calls to Java to load the ads. Also, that our entire app runs through a single activity on Java side (`AppActivity`).

As [Google's API for AdMob for rewarded videos](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) uses a singleton object to load and show ads, I've managed to dispatch the callbacks from google's API to the correct ad units on my own.

How can I show one rewarded video ad while loading another at same time? I have one single `Context` from my single `AppActivity`, so I can get only one  instance from `MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(context)`.

**Example**

Let's say that I have two ad units: AdUnit1 and AdUnit2.
I have successfully loaded AdUnit1 (`onAdLoaded()` called). Now, I call `loadAd()` for AdUnit2.

Now my AdUnit1 is loaded and AdUnit2 is loading. At that moment, if I call `isLoaded()`, it returns false, and if I call `show()`, it does nothing.

I suspect that the singleton is in an internal state of "loading", so not considered loaded or ready to show. AdUnit1 is already loaded and I want to show it, but I can't specify the ad unit when calling `show()` or when checking `isLoaded()` in Google's API.

Is it possible to show one rewarded video ad while loading another at same time? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered using the official AdMob C++ API? https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/cocos2d-x

Comment: Not really... But if they don't have support for multiple ad units on Java, they probably won't have it on C++...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to load more than one ad at a time from AdMob. You can show an ad and begin loading the next in `onRewardedVideoAdClosed`, but that's as close as it gets.

Comment: That's what I've found too.